# SoapUI shows incorrect response

Tags: c#, web-services, soapui, asmx

I'm trying to get return string from .asmx, but I found problem when I get return string (that contains other language), I can't read it.

My .asmx

```
public string HelloWorld(string message)
{
    return message;
}
```

I call HelloWorld() by SoapUI as picture below.

[image]

I get return string as picture below.
In XML, it's correct.

[image]

But in Raw, it's incorrect. It's ***Hello เธชเธงเธฑเธชเธ”เธต***. How to get correct above?

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcQWtrYXBvbGtcUHJvamVjdFxzbXdcc2VydmljZXMuYXNteA==?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 16 Aug 2017 07:36:37 GMT
Content-Length: 332

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><HelloWorldResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><HelloWorldResult>Hello เธชเธงเธฑเธชเธ”เธต</HelloWorldResult></HelloWorldResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: I can see in the image you are not passing Hello World ? rather you are passing Hello <some other language>

Comment: I can passing Hello <some other language> and I can debug in my .asmx file and I can see value of message.
The return string in XML is Hello <some other language>.
But the return string in Raw is Hello เธชเธงเธฑเธชเธ”เธต.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raw from SoapUI response can't show correct of other language (non English).
However, I call this web service from PL/SQL and Service Reference on Visual Studio then response can show correct of other language as normal.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your asmx web service converted **UTF-8** to **ASCII characters**, can you try changing version of SOAP protocol from version 1.1 to 1.2 ?

Follow this [doc](https://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/working-with-wsdls.html) for ***creating SOAP 1.2 requests***

Comment: Hi. It's still same result. I will find how to response by UTF-8 in asmx.